# FB.api error when fb.getLoginStatus works

Tags: javascript, facebook

very frustrated with javascript SDK for facebook.

can someone tell me why this works (gives an alert with my facebook name):

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

      if (response.authResponse) {
        token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
             // do something here they are logged in and have given you perms   
        });
      } else {
        // no user session available, someone you dont know
      }
    });
```

But this returns an error, "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.":

```
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook javascript api call returning undefined](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12651174/facebook-javascript-api-call-returning-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

> But this returns an error, "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Well, because you haven’t acquired an access token before calling the method …?

`FB.getLoginStatus` provides you with a fresh user access token, provided the user has authorized your app before.

But if you skip this step of interaction with Facebook – where do you expect a valid access token to come from?

Right, there is none – and therefore you are getting the error message, stating *exactly that* …

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How does one get the access token if not through logging in and connecting to facebook?